Unable to find category and price for tickets in requests
I have been lurking through the site: https://www.ticketcorner.ch for three days, but I am unable to find some ticket data in requests.
The purpose is to make a script that takes event url and gives a list of available tickets.
Now, I am getting some of the data from the requests like Block, Row and Seat No. but I am unable to find the category and the Price of the individual ticket (If I know one of these I can get other).

Now, for each available seat (highlighted in colors) I am able to get the Row: V, Seat No: 38, Block: Parterre Pair from the following requests url: https://api.eventim.com/seatmap/api/SeatMapHandler?smcVersion=v6.1&version=v6.2.11&cType=web&cId=8&evId=17988010&a_holds=1&a_rowRules=1&key=web_8_17988010_0_TCS_0&a_systemId=1&a_promotionId=0&a_sessionId=TCS_NO_SESSION&timestamp=28548647&expiryTime=28548657&chash=8S7qZoIgwA&signature=8QDkUbymqOzx1jjF5t9x_f1ca4QdW79RM25nSJiN3h4&fun=seatinfos&blockId=11
But I also need to get the Category: Kat. 3 and Price: 77.40 for each individual ticket
What I have achieved myself is explained in this answer I just saw,
Extract ticketcorner event seat prices from a venue map
Note: I want to do it using requests for some reason and can not shift to selenium or other browser automation framework. I do not want any code or detailed explanation, only a hint that from where I can get the data would be great help
If anyone can help me find the Category and price for the individual available ticket it would be great help, I have been trying for 3 days but in vain.
Thanks for any help in advance

When you click the given seat, you don’t see a request with the category and price information come through? If you do see that, just trace in back in the console window. And while you cannot use Selenium, or another browser automation framework, I’d still pull it up and use it’s ability to determine tags and references in order to get a better insight into the SeatMap…. chances are seats are tagged with a give class/id/etc..

No, I get category and price in other requests before the SeatMap though it is not connected to any of the seats, it just tells which cat has what price.

This was kind of a headache, but hopefully it solves your problem.
I'm going to assume you already saw the chunk of json that loads with the page load that lists the category with the corresponding price.
When you get to the part where you say you want to select a specific seat, this endpoint is fetched:

which has this response:

In there, you can see there is a property blocks where each item in this array corresponds to the categories you got in the original json. (ie. blocks[0] has the data for category 1)
Later when you hover over a seat, this endpoint is fetched if it's the first time you're hovering over a seat in that category:

Here is one from a different category:

You can see the block parameter in the request are the given block ids above, just with the 'b' removed from the start of the id.
The responses for these requests have the seat data for that block, and therefore for that category:

Each item inside of seatInfos is a seat with a given row and seat number. And if you want to get all the seats, you would just have to run these requests for each block in the first SeatMapHandler response.
Hopefully this made sense.

There is no connection between the Block and category, which is the actual problem. We have to find connection of cat with seat.
For example, this particular event: https://www.ticketcorner.ch/en/event/bejart-ballet-lausanne-deux-creations-bolero-theatre-de-beaulieu-17988010/
If you see the block "b11", you can see that s2175 in seatinfos is of Cat2, while the seat s708 is of cat3.
